# Why don't my wtmp/utmp reset the user count?

Tags: login, slackware, lightdm, w, wtmp

On a normal working Linux machine the command `w`
report 2 users(because 2 users are connected)

```
w
 19:23:19 up  1:53,  2 users,  load average: 0,44, 0,63, 0,81
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
```

after reboot report correctly 1 user

```
w
 19:26:44 up  1:03,  1 users,  load average: 0,44, 0,73, 0,90
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
```

On my Slackware current `w` reports the sum(!) of the previous users + the actual user connected, after 4 reboots it report 4 users.

```
w
 19:28:16 up  1:58,  4 users,  load average: 0,26, 0,59, 0,76
```

Why? I use Lightdm. Is it possible to use Xreset with a properly sessreg line like XDM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found using a Xreset script

First I edit the script(if not exist create it)

```
vim /etc/lightdm/Xreset

    #!/bin/sh
    sessreg -d -l $DISPLAY $USER

chmod 755 /etc/lightdm/Xreset
```

Then I edit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

```
session-cleanup-script=/etc/lightdm/Xreset
```

After reboot w report the correct number of users, which is 2
one for Xsession, one for shell opened.